# Select Tables' names in mySQL only if they have a specific element

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an undefined number of tables (x). How can I make SQL retrieve only the names of the tables that include a specific record? (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in one step, because the SQL language requires that the table(s) are fixed at the time the query is prepared. You can't write one query that queries an undefined number of tables.

I have to comment that it sounds like it might be a flawed design if you need to query an undefined number of tables. This is a [code smell](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html) -- not a guarantee of a bad design, because every rule has exceptions, but *probably* bad design.

Anyway, what I recommend as a solution is to begin by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find tables that contain the column you are going to search.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name = 'phone_number';
```

That query will return some number of matches. Then you can write application code to loop over the results, interpolating the schema/table names into a separate query.

Example in PHP:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `%s`.`%s` WHERE phone_number = ?",
      $row["table_schema"], $row["table_name"]);
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt2->execute([$phone_number]);
    $results[] = $stmt2->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. But I can't use this solution because all the tables contain the same columns. But some of this tables contains a special value in one of this columns. And there are a lot of tables in this DB, so I think that the request will be very slow